# Is there an "AllIndexesOf" method?

Tags: c#, .net, indexof

**Background:**

I'm working on an evaluator (I know there's solutions available, but I need some features that I need to implement myself). I need to find all occurrences of open brackets in the evaluation. However, for that I need all the indexes of the brackets.

**Question:**

Is there something like an AllIndexesOf method that returns a `int[]`, or `IEnumerable<int>`?

Comment: Why close votes? I get duplicate votes, but why close votes. Btw, title was so different I missed it, thanks Tim!

Comment: Downvoter, please explain!

Comment: _"I get duplicate votes, but why close votes"_ Duplicate votes **are** close votes.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but this question was asked many times even if in slightly different contextes. [google](http://tinyurl.com/dyqk3jl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not but you can get all the indexes using the following LINQ query.

```
int number  = 10;
int[] intArray = new[] { 1, 32, 10, 5, 65, 6, 10, 10 };
var allIndexes = intArray.Select((r,i)=> new {value = r, index = i})
                         .Where(r=> r.value == number)
                         .Select(r=> r.index);
```

`allIndexes` will contain `2,6 and 7`

Answer (score 4):

You also can use `Enumerable.Range`

```
 var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                         .Where(index => list[index] == yourValue);
```

Comment: That's quite clean. Thanks!